# Antlr4 DM string lexer rules

Tags: antlr, antlr4, lexer

I'm trying to represent the BYOND DM language strings in lexer form (See http://byond.com and http://byond.com/docs/ref). Here are the rules for strings:

- The string start and end with double quotes. i.e. `"hello world"` evaluates to `hello world`
- A backslash acts as an escape character, which can escape the end quote. i.e. `"hello\"world"` evaluates to `hello"world`
- Newlines in the string can be ignored by ending the line with a backslash. i.e. `"hello\
  world"` evaluates to `helloworld`
- If the string opens/closes with the sequence `{"`/`"}` respectively, newlines are allowed and entered into the final string. The sequence `\\\n` is still ignored
- The string can contain embedded expressions inside braces which are formatted into the result. Backslashes can escape the opening brace. i.e. `"hello [ "world" ] \["` evaluates to `hello world [` at run-time. Any expression can go in the braces (calls, math, etc...)
- If the starting quote/curly brace is prefixed with '@' escape sequences and embedded expressions are disabled for the string. i.e. `@{"hello [worl\d"}` and `@"hello [worl\d"` both evaluate to `hello [worl\d`

I am trying to construct ANTLR4 .g4 lexer rules to tokenize these strings. I figure there's 4 (or more) token types I'd need:

- Normal string. i.e `"hello world"`, `@"hello world"`, `@{"hello world"}` or `{"hello world"}`
- String start before embedded expression. i.e. `"hello [` or `{"hello [`
- String end after embedded expression. i.e. `] world"` or `] world"}`
- String in between two embedded expressions. i.e. `] hello world [`

Here are my (incomplete and unsuccessful) attempts:

```
LSTRING: '"' ('\\[' | ~[[\r\n])* '[';
RSTRING: ']' ('\\"' | ~["\r\n])* '"'; 
CSTRING: ']' ('\\[' | ~[[\r\n])* '['; 
FSTRING: '"' ('\\"' | ~["\r\n])* '"';
```

If this can't be solved in the lexer, I can write the parser rules on my own with the tokens `@`, `{"`, `"}`, `[`, `]`, `\\`, and `"`. But, I figure I'd give this a shot since it'd be more performant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with the following lexer tidbits. [Permalink](https://github.com/typemaker-lang/typemaker/blob/3b920878e9eeb1bc6510268e4e13882bf092b882/src/Typemaker.Parser/TypemakerLexer.g4)

```
...
@lexer::members
{
ulong regularAccessLevel;
System.Collections.Generic.Stack<bool> multiString = new System.Collections.Generic.Stack<bool>();
}
...
VERBATIUM_STRING: '@"' (~["\r\n])* '"';
MULTILINE_VERBATIUM_STRING: '@{"' (~'"')* '"}';
MULTI_STRING_START: '{"' { multiString.Push(true); } -> pushMode(INTERPOLATION_STRING);
STRING_START: '"' { multiString.Push(false); } -> pushMode(INTERPOLATION_STRING);
...
LBRACE: '[' { ++regularAccessLevel; };
RBRACE: ']' { if(regularAccessLevel > 0) --regularAccessLevel; else if(multiString.Count > 0) { PopMode(); } };
...
mode INTERPOLATION_STRING;
CHAR_INSIDE: '\\\''
    | '\\"'
    | '\\['
    | '\\\\'
    | '\\0'
    | '\\a'
    | '\\b'
    | '\\f'
    | '\\n'
    | '\\r'
    | '\\t'
    | '\\v'
    ;

EMBED_START: '[' -> pushMode(DEFAULT_MODE);
MULTI_STRING_CLOSE: {multiString.Peek()}? '"}' { multiString.Pop(); PopMode(); };
STRING_CLOSE: {!multiString.Peek()}? '"' { multiString.Pop(); PopMode(); };
STRING_INSIDE: {!multiString.Peek()}? ~('[' | '\\' | '"' | '\r' | '\n')+;
MULTI_STRING_INSIDE: {multiString.Peek()}? ~('[' | '\\' | '"')+;
```

Certain strings can cause it to emit multiple `STRING_INSIDE`/`MULTI_STRING_INSIDE` tokens in sequence, but this is acceptable since the parser will eat it all anyway.

A lot of it came from reading the C# interpolated strings in the antlr4 examples [permalink](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/edc36d1/csharp/CSharpLexer.g4)